# Truncate text at word boundaries

Tags: javascript

I want to convert the character limit to a word limit as it cuts off half way through some words in my paragraphs but I am unsure on what to add/change.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var nInitialCount = 180; //Intial characters to display
  var moretext = "Read more >";
  var lesstext = "Read less";
  $('.longtext').each(function() {
    var paraText = $(this).html();
    if (paraText.length > nInitialCount) {
      var sText = paraText.substr(0, nInitialCount);
      var eText = paraText.substr(nInitialCount, paraText.length - nInitialCount);
      var newHtml = sText + '<span class="moretext"><span>' + eText + '</span><a href="" class="links">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
      $(this).html(newHtml);
    }
  });

  $(".links").on('click', function(e) {
    var lnkHTML = $(this).html();
    if (lnkHTML == lesstext) {
      $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
      $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="longtext">
  Text here<br>
  <br> Text here as well<br>
  <br> More Text here
</div>
<button class="links">Read less</button>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for css word-wrap? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Comment: (Note re the question edit:  I added the button, since that was obviously needed to make the snippet usable. @JordanNorcross please review the edit to make sure I didn't misunderstand your intent in that code; apologies if so!)

Comment: @DanielBeck thank you for adding that in for me (I am new to this) the code seems to run fine. Any idea on how to update the JavaScript from a Character count to a Word Count?

Comment: @ControlAltDel thank you for the reply, i will check it out and get back to you on this one

Comment: @ControlAltDel No that is not want i wanted, the JavaScript just overwrites the word wrap.